# Magento throwing 500 server error to few customers

Tags: magento-enterprise

We are facing a weird issue where Magento throws 500 server error to very few customers. The error log says `PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 2147483648 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 96 bytes)`. Notice we already gave 2GB of memory_limit in PHP, so this is definitely not the memory issue but something else. We tried many ways to reproduce this without any luck. Once the customer gets this 500 error, s/he gets it all the time when they visit our website again.

What could be wrong? How to reproduce this kind of error?

Comment: I know that you excellent magento developer.....In this case  as my thought there are some coding issue in  your magento system. You may be fix by  enabling Magento profile and debug mode.

Comment: Thanks Amit. The point is errors are coming only on live and it's not happening all the time, just for few customers every few days so could not even reproduce it.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely a Memory issue as **2147483648 bytes** equals to about **2GB**, which is the memory_limit you set for PHP.

You may want to try increasing the memory_limit further and see if the client continues to see the same error.

Comment: 2GB is more than enough and I'm afraid to increase it beyond that. Most of the time (even when running promos when we see lot of traffic) we don't face any memory issues.

Comment: Something must be eating up the memory. Maybe a rogue extension? Anyway I will try to increase the memory_limit and see if the client continues to see the error message and if it's resolved, we can confirm that something is eating up the memory in your store.

Answer (score 0):

Have you solved this? I have the exact same issue, driving me crazy

(can't add comment)